# Transfer data between unbound DataGridViews

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview in form 1 which contains unbound data. How can I transfer the data from datagridview in another datagridview2 which is located in form2? Give me some suggestions please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had the DataGridView bound to a table, you would just set a reference in Form2 to the table.  In your case, you probably want to have a reference to the actual DataGridView in the second form.

It's not the best programming style from a maintenance perspective — it's better to use a data source.

Here is a simple idea of one way to show the second DataGridView with the data from the first DataGridView.  It's not perfect, but it should show you the idea.

```
public Form2(DataGridView dgvFromFom1) {
  InitializeComponent();

  foreach (DataGridViewColumn dc in dgvFromForm1.Columns) {
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dc.Name, dc.HeaderText);
  }

  foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgvFromForm1.Rows) {
    Object[] newRow = new object[dr.Cells.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < newRow.Length; i++) {
      newRow[i] = dr.Cells[i].Value;
    }
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(newRow);
  }      
}
```

Again, though, this would be a lot easier using a DataSource.

Comment: It is not working...Could you give me an example how i could complete the otherDataGridView with data ?

Comment: @EmilDumbazu Are you looking to *read* the data from the grid in Form1, or show the same grid from Form1 on Form2?  Depends what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is there a solution for this ?

Comment: @EmilDumbazu I updated the example.  Also, found this blog talking about it: [Copying a DataGridViewRow to another DataGridView Control](http://canlu.blogspot.com/2009/06/copying-datagridviewrow-to-another.html)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to transfer data betwwen `Forms` or `Grids`. The thing is that if you figure our that need to **share** a data between them, just define a facade class that holds a data, and all that parts of your application (`Forms`, `Grids`, something else) consume data from that single, *exactly same* instance.

That is.